# Swift Packages Manager install Facebook sdk,how to use the object-c package FBSDKCoreKit,FBSDKLoginKit

Tags: facebook, swift-package-manager

I'm using  Swift Packages Manager to install Facebook sdk and I only need the object-c package。

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/26W91.png)

does any body know how to switch the  swift package to ios package?

The Package.swift file cannot be edit.

Comment: daemon,the document says:    If you explicitly DO NOT want to include Swift, import FBSDKCoreKit FBSDKLoginKit and FBSDKShareKit
For projects that include Swift, use FacebookCore, FacebookLogin, and FacebookShare。what should I do